# How to install Birt report designer in Eclipse 3.7.1

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, report-designer

I'm trying to follow a guide on installing specific report designer tool according to [report development guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21605970&aid=1)

I already finished most part, but just 1 thing doesn't succeed.

According to page 18 I need to change the target to

```
C:\birt371\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm “C:\Program Files\IBM\Java60\jre\bin\java.exe” –vmargs –Xmx512m
```

but because my jre is installed in

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe
```

I changed it to

```
C:\birt371\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm “C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe” –vmargs –Xmx512m
```

This gives me an error:

> a java runtime environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations "C:\Program

If I leave out the target

```
-vm “C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe” –vmargs –Xmx512m
```

so my target becomes

```
C:\birt371\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

Eclipse starts up normally, no errors.

The problem:

I can't import my reports and I'm wondering if this last peace of configuration has something to do with it.

The question:

**How can I use the configuration required?**

Notes:
With the previous java versions there wasn't a security in java (control panel), could my problem have something to do with that?

Comment: Which quote signs did you actually use? In your example calls, you seem to use “ and ”, and in the error message, it is ".

Comment: That's what's bugging me also, maybe it doesn't read the full path (breaking of after program not taking the full path specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-vm` argument forces a specific Java installation on your machine to be used. Especially useful if you have multiple Java's installed, or Eclipse cannot find Java.

If you have only one Java installed and Eclipse finds it ok, you can **simply launch without the `-vm`** argument.

From the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm?cp=0_3_0) for `-vm`:

> The location of Java Runtime Environment (JRE) to use to run the
>   Eclipse platform. If not specified, the launcher will attempt to find
>   a JRE. It will first look for a directory called jre as a sibling of
>   the Eclipse executable, and then look on the operating system path.
>   Relative paths are interpreted relative to the directory that eclipse
>   was started from.

If you do need to get `-vm` working, the recommended way is by editing `eclipse.ini` and putting `-vm` on one line and the full path to the vm on the next line. See the [eclipse.ini entry on the Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: Seems to have worked, but even without the change in the ini file it already the program executed, so what's the difference?

Comment: If you don't have -vm in ini file or command line then eclipse normally just gets java off your PATH.